# Getting error in Displaying value coming from service in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-services, angular-module

I have a service in Key:value or in **countryCode** : **countryName** pair

**Servicve ->**

```
{"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BG": "Bulgaria", "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB": "Barbados", "WF": "Wallis and Futuna", "BL": "Saint Barthelemy", "BM": "Bermuda", "BN": "Brunei", "BO": "Bolivia", "BH": "Bahrain", "BI": "Burundi", "BJ": "Benin", "BT": "Bhutan", "JM": "Jamaica"}
```

I have created an Interface to receive value from the service

**interface**

```
export interface IcounrtyCode {
    code: string;
    country: string;
}
```

which is probably creating problem in receiving the value the way I want

if you see my response when I write **console.log( this.counrtyCode)**
It displays like ->

AD: "Andorra"
AE: "United Arab Emirates"
AF: "Afghanistan"
AG: "Antigua and Barbuda"
AI: "Anguilla"
AL: "Albania"

where AD is key and Andorra is value. **Maybe If I can able to change response in following way.  {[code:"AD",country:"country"]} then I can catch the response in my way** , I tried to do so But I am getting error 
How I can do that ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create yourself a sort of Dictionary interface

```
interface Dict {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

You should be able to map your response to that.

The issue you have is that you are trying to map your object to your `IcounrtyCode` interface but the json returned from the service is not in the correct shape.
It would need to be something like the below:

```
{["code": "BD", "country":"Bangladesh"]}
```

I would recommend changing the server response to the correct json format if you have control over the server code.

Answer (score -1):

Although some error trace would have been useful. But i guess you can try to format your data as following.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

 getData():IcounrtyCode[]{
  return [{code:"BD",country: "Bangladesh"}, {code:"BE", country:"Belgium"}]
 }
}

export interface IcounrtyCode {
  code: string;
  country: string;
}
```